# Python connection to OrientDB

Tags: python, orientdb, pyorient

I'm trying to connect to orientdb using pyorient but I receive the following error...

```
[...]
  File "C:\Users\civan\Documents\GitHub\code\venv\lib\site-packages\pyorient\orient.py", line 101, in connect
    raise PyOrientWrongProtocolVersionException(
pyorient.exceptions.PyOrientWrongProtocolVersionException: Protocol version 37 is not supported yet by this client.
```

I use an example code like this:

```
import pyorient

client = pyorient.OrientDB("etc", 2424)
session_id = client.db_open("db", "admin", "pass!")
sql = "SELECT id, name, ifnull(org_id, 1) AS org_id, create_dt.format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') AS create_dt FROM Client"
records = client.query(sql)
data = [o.oRecordData for o in records]
print(f'Fetched {len(data)} rows')
```

I tried the solution from:

> https://github.com/orientechnologies/pyorient/issues/27#issuecomment-647029817

But it didn't worked

**Anyway there is only old info, maybe you know something new?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually this code https://github.com/OpenConjecture/pyorient is the only answer and it works! You can remove the lines from orient.py by yourself or use the update from git. I had a double issue, one with the password and one with this connect and didn't realise the real source.